# Type conversions on references

Tags: c++, reference, type-conversion

I found sort of an unexpected behavior for const references:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void myfunction() {
    T b = 30;
    const int &i = b;
    cout << "Before change: " << i << endl;
    b = 33;
    cout << "After change: "  << i << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "int" << endl;
    myfunction<int>();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "double" << endl;
    myfunction<double>();
}
```

This gives the following result:

```
int
Before change: 30
After change: 33

double
Before change: 30
After change: 30
```

I understand that in the second case, &i does not reference b because it is a double, but does reference a temporary object. This is also the reason why the value of i isn't changed when changing b.

But why is such a behavior even allowed? In my opinion, it is counterintuitive. Is there any performance advantage to just use `const int i = b`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you do "const T &i = b;"  when templating?

Comment: I find nothing counterintuitive about saner cases of `const T&x=y;` when a reference to the type of `y` can be implicitly cast to a `T&`.  The counterintuitive part is when a value of the type of `y` is implicitly used to construct a temporary of type `T` for that reference.  That is unlikely enough to be the programmer's intent, that I would expect a warning.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but the more interesting version of the same question would be a function that takes two parameters `T&,int const&` and modifies the first then displays the second.  If you pass the same `int` to both, you would expect modifying the first to change the second.  If you pass the same `double` to both, I would think there is less reason to want a compiler warning on the creation of a temporary `int` for the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually think of

```
const int &i = b;
```

as

```
int const* const p_i = &b;
```

with an automatic dereferencing, like (but don't take this too literally!)

```
#define i (*p_i)
```

The first `const` there says you can't change `b` via the pointer/reference. But you can change it via other means. Then what you see *via* the pointer/reference is changed.

In the case where `b` is of type `double` the reference can't refer directly to it. What you get then is a *temporary* `int`, converted from the `double`, whose lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the reference (and the pointer view of things breaks down a little!). In this case a change made to the original is not reflected in the temporary that the reference refers to.

---

In passing, this kind of aliasing (two or more ways to refer to the same thing, with different restrictions) is an in-principle problem with passing by reference to `const`. Happily it's not much of a problem in practice. In fact, I've never encountered it except when creating silly examples to teach about the technical possibility.

---

Regarding

> **”** But why is such a behavior even allowed?

… this asks about two issues:

- Lifetime extension of temporary when binding to reference.
- Implicit conversion from `double` to `int`.

When I asked Bjarne about the rationale for the lifetime extension, in the old days when everybody (including Bjarne) used the comp.lang.c++ Usenet group, he replied that it was mainly for consistency of rules.

The potentially and usually information-destroying implicit conversion from `double` to `int`, and in general from any built-in numerical type to another, is there from the old C days. In C++11 and later you can restrict the allowed conversion by using braced initializers. Thus, if you write

```
const int &i = {b};
```

… then the code just won't compile for the case where `b` is of type `double`, because that would be a *narrowing conversion*.

Of course that doesn't help for, for example, type `short` (no longer a narrowing conversion), but it helps a little.

Comment: "Happily it's not much of a problem in practice." Yeah. In fact, it's only a problem if one spends some effort on making it one, like the questioner did.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I can not agree that this is counterintuitive.

Consider the following example

```
struct A
{
    A( double x ) : x ( x ) {}
    double x;
};

const A &ra1 = A( 10.0 );
const A &ra2 = 10.0;
```

I think you will say nothing against these declarations of the references. And they are intuitive.

Now simply substitute the class name `A` for type `int` and you will get

```
const int &ri1 = int( 10.0 );
const int &ri2 = 10.0;
```

In my opinion there is a logic.

For example MS VC++ generates a warning for the last declaration

> warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'const
>   int', possible loss of data

As for the performance advantage then you should look through the generated object code. It can occur such a way that for the both declarations the compiler generates the same object code.

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily counterintuitive that `const A &ra2=10.0;` works.  But it is still counterintuitive that it doesn't generate a warning.  It is an obscure enough action that requiring the explicit constructor call to clarify programmer intent (avoid a warning) is reasonable.  I'm more concerned with `const A&ra2=foo.get_value();` when that causes a temporary `A` to be constructed after the function returns something else, I want a warning.  If I wanted a temporary `A` constructed, I would have indicated that explicitly.